# Is There A Built-In Way to Split Strings In C++?

Tags: c++, string, split

well is there?  by string i mean std::string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string

Comment: As much as I love C++, I still hate warping my mind around its strings.

Comment: ah right. looks like a duplicate question. i recommend closing this one then and redirect people to the other "c-how-to-split-a-string". what do ya think?

Comment: hmm i'm just reading the other question allows to have spaces in the string. maybe one should not close this one then. not sure anymore :)

Comment: The questioner doesn't specify how he wants to split the strings, so assuming duplicate makes sense unless he makes it clear he wants something different.

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a perl-style split function I use:

```
void split(const string& str, const string& delimiters , vector<string>& tokens)
{
    // Skip delimiters at beginning.
    string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
    // Find first "non-delimiter".
    string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

    while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
    {
        // Found a token, add it to the vector.
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
        // Find next "non-delimiter"
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Unlike most other solutions, it doesn't require boost, combines delimiters, supports multiple delimiters, is well documented, and is fairly compact and easy to understand for noobs like me. I'd just change the delimeters parameter to take a default, as in the original: http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html  :-)

Comment: Also, noobs like me should be careful to clear the vector each time they call this function if they expect it to only hold the last set of tokens! (use tokens.clear()).

Comment: Old thread that showed up in a search. I would change the signature of `split` to not have a third parameter, and return the `vector<string>` instead (`tokens` will be a local variable).

Answer (score 11):

There's no built-in way to split a string in C++, but [boost](http://www.boost.org) provides the [string algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) library to do all sort of string manipulation, including string [splitting](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id4002194).

Answer (score 10):

Yup, stringstream.

```
std::istringstream oss(std::string("This is a test string"));
std::string word;
while(oss >> word) {
    std::cout << "[" << word << "] ";
}
```

Comment: This is my work-horse splitter.  If you want to split on a delimiter, you can just replace `oss>>word` with `getline(oss, word, ':')`

Answer (score 7):

**STL strings**

You can use string iterators to do your dirty work.

```
std::string str = "hello world";

std::string::const_iterator pos = std::find(string.begin(), string.end(), ' '); // Split at ' '.

std::string left(str.begin(), pos);
std::string right(pos + 1, str.end());

// Echoes "hello|world".
std::cout << left << "|" << right << std::endl;
```

Comment: Would this be then applicable only for a two word string??

Answer (score 3):

```
void split(string StringToSplit, string Separators)
{
    size_t EndPart1 = StringToSplit.find_first_of(Separators)
    string Part1 = StringToSplit.substr(0, EndPart1);
    string Part2 = StringToSplit.substr(EndPart1 + 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, if this ends up in some opensource program somewhere, will i need to give you credit :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You have to break them up using one of the library functions.

Something I use:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse(std::string l, char delim) 
{
    std::replace(l.begin(), l.end(), delim, ' ');
    std::istringstream stm(l);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    for (;;) {
        std::string word;
        if (!(stm >> word)) break;
        tokens.push_back(word);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

You can also take a look at the `basic_streambuf<T>::underflow()` method and write a filter.

Answer (score 0):

What the heck...  Here's my version...

Note:  Splitting on ("XZaaaXZ", "XZ") will give you 3 strings.  2 of those strings will be empty, and **won't** be added to theStringVector if theIncludeEmptyStrings is false.

Delimiter is **not** any element in the set, but rather matches that exact string.

```
 inline void
StringSplit( vector<string> * theStringVector,  /* Altered/returned value */
             const  string  & theString,
             const  string  & theDelimiter,
             bool             theIncludeEmptyStrings = false )
{
  UASSERT( theStringVector, !=, (vector<string> *) NULL );
  UASSERT( theDelimiter.size(), >, 0 );

  size_t  start = 0, end = 0, length = 0;

  while ( end != string::npos )
  {
    end = theString.find( theDelimiter, start );

      // If at end, use length=maxLength.  Else use length=end-start.
    length = (end == string::npos) ? string::npos : end - start;

    if (    theIncludeEmptyStrings
         || (   ( length > 0 ) /* At end, end == length == string::npos */
             && ( start  < theString.size() ) ) )
      theStringVector -> push_back( theString.substr( start, length ) );

      // If at end, use start=maxSize.  Else use start=end+delimiter.
    start = (   ( end > (string::npos - theDelimiter.size()) )
              ?  string::npos  :  end + theDelimiter.size()     );
  }
}


inline vector<string>
StringSplit( const  string  & theString,
             const  string  & theDelimiter,
             bool             theIncludeEmptyStrings = false )
{
  vector<string> v;
  StringSplit( & v, theString, theDelimiter, theIncludeEmptyStrings );
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no common way doing this.

I prefer the [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html), its header only and easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

**C strings**

Simply insert a `\0` where you wish to split.  This is about as built-in as you can get with standard C functions.

This function splits on the first occurance of a `char` separator, returning the second string.

```
char *split_string(char *str, char separator) {
    char *second = strchr(str, separator);
    if(second == NULL)
        return NULL;

    *second = '\0';
    ++second;
    return second;
}
```

Comment: @cdonner, Because strchr is simpler.  =]

Comment: @strager: This is bad design -- modifying the input. Though this is something strtok() has been doing and has gotten away with.

Comment: @dirkgently, Eh, I misread strtok as strchr with multiple separators.  Didn't know much about the function.  My bad ...  Also, I wouldn't say it's bad design.  If documented properly it'd be quite clear, IMO.

Comment: strtok isn't reentrant.  However, it would be perfectly reasonable to use a strtok-like facility that starts out by copying the input string into its own buffer, to avoid modifying input or global state.

Comment: @epochwolf, At the time of posting this, the original question did not mention C strings or std::string.

Answer (score -2):

A fairly simple method would be to use the c_str() method of std::string to get a C-style character array, then use strtok() to tokenize the string. Not quite as eloquent as some of the other solutions listed here, but it's easy and works.

Comment: strtok writes into the memory pointed to. c_str() points to memory which must not be written to (invariant of the string class - might silently break things like copy-on-write semantics). the C++ standard forbids it. u can copy to a std::vector first, then you can use strtok though.

Comment: The c_str method returns a const string which points to the internal representation.  It's const so you'd also have to strdup it or copy it to a vector.  A C++ way was asked for so I'm downvoting this.