# How to split a string?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is There A Built-In Way to Split Strings In C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599989/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-split-strings-in-c)

i have one string variable which contains:
string var = "this_is.that_alos" how i can separate only "that_alos" from it.
i.e. i need only second part after "that_alos"

Comment: You need to be more precise with what you want... Will the string have only one '.' in it? If not, do you want the part after the first '.', the last '.', or is there some other method you would want to use?

Comment: And maybe consider deleting the `C` tag, if you're _really_ using C++. My answer below assumes C is fine, because that's what I'm familiar with :) but if you really want a C++-idiomatic answer, please update the tags and I'll delete my answer. Thanks

Comment: plz don't use "pls" and other such abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string var = "this_is.that_alos";
std::string part = var.substr(var.find_first_of('.'));
```

If you want to exclude the `'.'`, just add 1:

```
std::string part = var.substr(var.find_first_of('.') + 1);
```

Comment: it is working but im getting "." also in the part string. how to avoid "."

Comment: @balaji: See my edit. I strongly recommend you read the documentation for these methods. This is a very simple task, and with the slightest amount of search, you could have solved it yourself.

Comment: I think that by answering questions like this we're actually doing the OP a disservice and ourselves as well by unleashing very bad programmers with no research or thinking skills on the world.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the usual function is `strchr(3)`:

```
char * second_half = strchr(var, '.');
```

Of course, this is just a new pointer to the middle of the string. If you start writing into this string, it changes the one and only copy of it, which is also pointed to by `char *var`. (Again, assuming C.)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string var = "this_is.that_alos";

std::string::iterator start = std::find(var.begin(), var.end(), '.')
std::string second(start + 1, var.end());
```

But you should check if `start + 1` is not `var.end()`, if `var` don't contain any dot.

Comment: `std::string::find_first_of` does not return an iterator.

Comment: You are right, but I'm wondering why, if all other find operation return an iterator?

Comment: You can use `std::find` though.

Comment: std::string was added to C++ standard before STL, which is why it has its own find functions that return indices, not iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use string indexing or iterators, you can use `std::getline`

```
std::string var = "this_is.that_alos";
std::istringstream iss(var);

std::string first, second;

std::getline(iss, first, '.');
std::getline(iss, second, '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok` for splitting the String, with the Special character as "."
for ex

```
string var = "this_is.that_alos";
string Parts[5] = strtok(&var[0],".");
string SubPart = Parts[1];
```

Hope it will help U.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use boost::regex (soon to be
std::regex).  It's not clear what the exact requirements are,
but they should be easy to specify using a regular expression.

Otherwise (and using regular expressions could be considered
overkill for this), I'd use the usual algorithms, which work for
any sequence.  In this case, std::find will find the first '.',
use it with reverse iterators to find the last, etc.

-- 
James Kanze